# How can I trigger a button click event in a C# Windows Forms application when the user presses the "Enter" key from anywhere in the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Windows Forms application that includes a text box control and a button control. I want to allow the user to press the "Enter" key in the text box to trigger the button click event, even if the text box does not have focus (i.e. without clicking into the text box first).

I've tried using the KeyDown, KeyUp, and KeyPress events of the text box, button even a Form control to handle the "Enter" key press, but none of them seem to work when the text box does not have focus. I've also tried setting the AcceptsReturn property of the text box to false to disable the default behavior of the "Enter" key, but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

The thing is that if I use another key, it works with Form_KeyDown, but as soon as I try to use Enter, it closes the application every time without focusing on the TextBox

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { BtnEquals.PerformClick(); }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try the AcceptButton property of the form. But it won't work if the textbox is a multiline textbox.

Comment: you can call your event-handler like any other function in your code, so e.g. in your keydown-method just call `buttonOk_Clikck(this, new EventArgs());`

Comment: The companion of the AcceptButton is the CancelButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the form's ProcessCmdKey or ProcessDialogKey method and process the Enter key there.

Answer (score 0):

//Added this for Enter Key button press...WHEJr...7/27/2023...
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
{
if (m.Msg == 0x0100 && (int)m.WParam == 13)
{
//this.ProcessTabKey(true);
button1.PerformClick();
}
return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
}